# How to combine an insert statement and an update statement in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table (try), having a primary key (pk), several data fields (dx, dy, dz), and a time field (td). In sqlite3, I would like to:

1. Insert a record(pk, dx, dy, dz) if it (pk) does not exist.
2. If record exists, update it.
3. During update, If there is any change to some of the fields (dx,dy) update td to current time.
4. During update, If there was no change in above fields (dx,dy) leave td as is (original time).

REPLACE comes close to what I need, but it does an "insert" or "replace all", while I need an "insert" or "update a few".

Here is something that works, but this needs that 2 statements
One to check if record exists first, then next to do insert or update. How to perform these in a single statement?

```
-- Example table
CREATE TABLE try(
    pk INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
    dx TEXT NOT NULL,   -- update td if this changes.
    dy TEXT,            -- update td if this changes.
    dz TEXT,            -- no need to change td, if this changes.
    td DATETIME DEFAULT (strftime('%s','now'))
);

-- 1. Check if record exists or not.
SELECT pk from try where pk=1;

-- 2.a If record does not exist, do this insert.
INSERT INTO try(pk, dx, dy, td) VALUES(1, 'data_x', 'data_y', 'data_z', strftime('%s', 'now'));

-- 2.b If record exists, update but be selective with td.
UPDATE try SET dx='data_x',
               dy='data_y_new',
               dz='data_z_new',
               td=(CASE WHEN (try.dx IS NOT 'data_x' OR try.dy IS NOT 'data_y_new') THEN strftime('%s','now')
                        ELSE try.td
                   END)
           WHERE pk=1;
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a single statement?

Comment: In my application I will end up checking if record exists or not, and then I will do an insert or update. I would like to combine all this in single DB statement, so that scope another thread doing the same between check and op is minimized - though I can do locking, but preferred if this can be contained within the DB layer, rather than application layer.

Comment: Just use transactions. (If you don't use them explicitly, SQLite will wrap an implicit transaction around every statement, so you do not lose any performance.)

Comment: I see, will check that out. Also, I am close to be able to combine - will update soon..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to combine the statements for my requirement, and here it goes just for reference, for someone else who might need it later. However, note that working with multiple statements within a transaction (as suggested by CL) might be simpler, in general..

```
REPLACE INTO try VALUES(1,
                        'data_x',
                        'data_y_new',
                        'data_z_new',
                        CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT td FROM try AS try2 WHERE (try2.pk IS 1 AND try2.dx IS 'data_x' AND try2.dy IS 'data_y_new'))
                             THEN (SELECT td FROM try AS try3 WHERE (try3.pk IS 1))
                             ELSE strftime('%s','now')
                             END);
```